# Performance of StringBuilder.append

Tags: java, string, performance, stringbuffer

It's recommended (PMD rule AppendCharacterWithChar) to use `StringBuilder.append(char)` instead of `StringBuilder.append(String)`. I agree with that.

But if I want to append a (short) string like `"='"` or `"</"`, is using

```
StringBuilder.append('=').append('\'')
```

better (faster) than

```
StringBuilder.append("='")
```

?

Comment: You'd get a more substantial performance boost by switching to `StringBuilder`.

Comment: This won't make any noticeable difference. Switch to StringBuilder, and use the version that is the most readable.

Answer (score 6):

[The code for the two methods is](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#StringBuffer.append%28char%29):

```
public synchronized StringBuffer append(char c) {
    toStringCache = null;
    super.append(c);
    return this;
}

public AbstractStringBuilder append(char c) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + 1);
    value[count++] = c;
    return this;
}
```

vs

```
public synchronized StringBuffer append(String str) {
    toStringCache = null;
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}

public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return appendNull();
    int len = str.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count += len;
    return this;
}
```

*Some* more work is done by the `append(String)` version, but it's trivial:

- Some null checking;
- Retrieving the length;
- Copying a range of characters.

But this isn't really going to make much of a difference, at least for *very short* strings.

The more significant performance cost here is in the fact that `StringBuffer` methods are `synchronized`: in order to invoke either overload, a monitor has to be acquired on the `StringBuffer`. This takes some time - I would have thought longer than the extra work done. And calling `append(char)` means you have to acquire this monitor repeatedly.

The real performance hit here is for the squidgy bit between monitor and keyboard - you. Write code that is readable: the `append(String)` form is *way* easier to read than calling `append(char)` form over and over.

Also, use `StringBuilder` if you can - this avoids the synchronization issue entirely.